# Are there any Julia commands which return an exit code depending on whether or not Julia is installed?

Tags: bash, julia

From what I understand:

```
 -e, --eval <expr>         Evaluate <expr>
```

is used to use a Julia command directly from terminal as opposed to typing out

```
usr$ julia
```

in order to enter the interactive shell.

Are there any commands in the format of:

```
usr$ julia -e <command_here>
```

that would allow terminal to return that Julia is not installed (if it is not) and return a different value (ie. corresponding to the command) if Julia is installed?

***Note:***

Most of Julia language commands only work within the Julia interactive shell, but I'd like a statement that does this within the bash shell of terminal.

Comment: If you just want to see if something will happen when you run `julia` you could try `command -v julia` and look at it's exit code, does that address your problem?

Comment: @EricRenouf thats along the lines of what I'm looking for. Could you give me an example of a command to test it out? I'm unfamiliar with Julia language and the documentation isn't helping.

Comment: That command is actually just `bash`, it's not specific to julia or anything else.  I'll write an answer showing it though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `bash` you could use the builtin `command` to get information about what will happen if you try to run a command.  One upshot from that is that you could use it to tell if nothing would happen as well, that is, if that command doesn't exist (as an executable, alias or function).  So if you run

```
command -v julia &>/dev/null
```

you could check `$?` to see if it found anything (0) or not (1).  So you could do

```
if command -v julia &>/dev/null; then
    echo "Something would happen"
else
    echo "Nothing would happen"
fi
```

note, however, that this wouldn't check if `julia` would actually do what you want.  This would be true if someone created a function named `julia`.

The solution from chrisaycock will give you more confidence that `julia` really does what you want, but it's up to you to decide whether or not the "risk" is worth it that someone overloaded the name on you.

Answer (score 3):

Just print something and capture it for comparison.

```
RESULT=$(julia -e 'println("Hello")' 2> /dev/null)

if [[ "$RESULT" == "Hello" ]];
then
  echo "installed"
else
  echo "missing"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

`bash` returns an exit status of 127 if it cannot find a command. You can use this to determine if the executable is found.

```
if julia -h 2> /dev/null; [[ $? -eq 127 ]]; then
  echo "Julia not found"
fi
```

Comment: On my old fedora install (14) it seems to be trying to find a package to suggest if I type a non-existent command, and exits with 0 regardless.  Perhaps that was just a bug with that version though, it doesn't seem to happen on newer ones or an Ubuntu or CentOS versions

Comment: I did forget to mention that some distributions might intercept not-found commands using the `command_not_found_handle` function.

Comment: That should only be an issue in an interactive shell, though.

Comment: Ah, good point about the interactive shell, thanks for the reminder there!